# AJAX Post request sending repeated requests

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm sending an AJAX POST request for a login form. If I put the wrong combination or I put the right combination, the ajax sends that request plus all the others

Incorrect login:

```
function incorrect() {
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');
    $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Username ou password incorretos!");
    $('input[type="password"]').val('');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Correct login:

```
function correct() {
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog');
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
    $('.error').addClass('alert alert-success').html("Logado com sucesso!");
    $("#reglogin").toggle();
    $("#conta").toggle();
}
```

Ajax call:

```
function loginAjax() {
    $("form").on("submit", function (x) {
        x.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Login/Login',
            traditional: true,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === false) {
                    incorrect();
                } else if (data === true) {
                    correct();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string passstr = Encrypt(password);
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select * from Cliente where Username='{0}' and Password='{1}'", username, passstr);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Session["Username"] = username;
                string valueFromSession = Session["Username"].ToString();

                conn.Close();
                return Json(data: true);
            } else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return Json(data: false);
            }

        }
```

I want to send only one request every time I submit the form

Thank You!

Comment: Is it possible youre calling `loginAjax()` multiple times which is attaching multiple handlers to the submit form?

Comment: Try changing `$("form").on("submit", function (x) {` to `$("form").off("submit").on("submit", function (x) {` to see if that helps.

Comment: I checked that and It's not repeated.
The .off("submit") worked for me, thx <3
@Steve

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `$("form").on("submit", function (x)` to `$("form").off("submit").on("submit", function (x)` and it worked